# Is it possible to JOIN with a var from a LEFT JOIN without destrorying rows?

Tags: t-sql, sqlite

My code generates a large query. A simple version is

```
SELECT * FROM main_table as mt
JOIN user_data AS ud ON mt.user_id=ud.id 
LEFT JOIN ban_Status AS bs ON  ud.status_id=bs.id
JOIN AnotherTable ON bs.data=AnotherTable.id
```

NOTE: This code is untested.

When i remove the last join i get results. I can also change it to left join but that would be wrong. If ud.status is not null i would like a join as i always do when i do a select query from ban_Status. How do i fix this? must i write left join on every table if i left join the parent table? would that not give me side effects?

I am using sqlite ATM but will switch to tsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the LEFT JOIN, but in your WHERE clause specify that either both ud.status_id is null and AnotherTable.id is null or neither is null.

```
SELECT * FROM main_table as mt
JOIN user_data AS ud ON mt.user_id=ud.id 
LEFT JOIN ban_Status AS bs ON  ud.status_id=bs.id
LEFT JOIN AnotherTable ON bs.data=AnotherTable.id
WHERE (ud.status_id is null and AnotherTable.id is null)
       or (ui.status_id is not null and AnotherTable.id is not null)
```

That will keep you from selecting any records that have a ban_Status but don't have the additional data from the other table.

Comment: +1. This seems to work but could you also explain why an INNER JOIN way down in a chain of LEFT JOINs seem to make all these LEFT JOINS behave as an INNER JOIN?

Comment: If the `LEFT JOIN` can't join a row, then it will return `NULL` in all his fields. Then, if you use a `INNER JOIN` on a  `NULL` id, the entire row will be discarded (due to the the `INNER JOIN` rule).

Comment: And it's not that the inner join was way down the list but that it joined to the table on the right side of the join. HAd it joined to the table aliased ud, you would not have had this problem. Still I ke to put all my left joins at the end of the joins, it kind of reminds me that if I join anything to them, I need to make it a left join as well.